# How to use a $result variable with table object in SQL query using mySQLi

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to make this code work, but it only works until the second echo statement `echo "Finished 2";`.

```
<?php
if (count($_GET) > 0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM winery WHERE winery_name='".$_GET['winery_name']."'";
echo "Finished 1";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 2";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM".$result."WHERE wine_type='".$_GET['wine_type']."'";
echo "Finished 3";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 4";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM".$result.", wine_variety WHERE wine_id=wine_variety.wine_id";
echo "Finished 5";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 6";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM".$result."WHERE variety_id='".$_GET['grape_variety']."'";
echo "Finished 7";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished all queries";

}
?>
```

The problem from my understanding is that sql doesn't recognize `$result` as a table, but `$result` stores the return table from my query. How can I make SQL use the return table from `$result` in a new query?

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to see the `query()` method code from your DB class

Comment: I am using mysqli. I am not defining the query().

Comment: I think you are missing the point of `$result`.

Comment: In that case `$result` is a `MYSQLI::Result` object. You must read whichever column you want to use from that resultset you cannot just use $result specially as you use `SELECT *` which will return more than one column

Comment: I understand it may not be possible to do this in sql--use return table in next query. I have only worked with relational algebra and it works on paper, so I guess I have to join the tables and create a new table in sql and use that for  new queries?

Comment: can i convert all the columns in $result into a table?

Comment: SHow us an example of what is being/or should be returned from each of these queries. Or show the schema for these tables

Comment: You are using `$result` where a TABLE NAME should be placed????

Comment: In relational algebra, the result of a SELECT query returns a table. I am trying to use that return table in new queries. I also added the picture of ER diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from your winery table you are fetching other table name???

If so you need to fetch row from the $result and then get appropriate column from winery table (i.e. column with other table name).

BTW best option would be joining two tables.

One more point where I think you are making mistake is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM".$result."WHERE wine_type='".$_GET['wine_type']."'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$result." WHERE wine_type='".$_GET['wine_type']."'";
```

space between FROM & double quote and between double quote and WHERE

To get winery_id from winary_name you can write your HTML form like

```
<select name="winary_id">
    <option value="Winary ID HERE">Winary Name Here</option> // you can generate your dynamic options like this which will return id instead of name
</select>
```

Comment: You are correct. My first statement is incorrect. It should be $sql = "SELECT * FROM wine WHERE winery_name='".$_GET['winery_name']."'";

Comment: Thank you it works now but I realize I need to do more to get winery_id from  $_GET['winery_name'] to make it work as intended.

Comment: from where you are getting winery_name??

Comment: You shoudl look at JOINing the tables. and getting all this in one query

Comment: if you are getting it from form and select tag then you can directly get id from there

Comment: Arjun Bala. Does $_GET['winery_name'] also contain informatino about winery_id? How can i access it? Thank you for your help and I am using a GET form.