# How to use a MySQLi return object as a table for new SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't understand how we can use the results that is a table from a `SELECT` query for new queries. Let's say we join two tables using `INNER JOIN` and we get a mysqli `return object` holding the rows of the joined table as an array. But how can I use this for new queries. I tried doing it by using the result object `$result` as a mysql table but it doesn't work, neither does doing `$result->fetch_all()` make it into a table.

I have a form that takes in `$_GET['winery_name']` and `$_GET['wine_type']`that are both strings in winery and wine_type tables. I need to go from their string value to their id values that are their primary keys and serve as foreign keys in wine table.

Depending on the winery_name and wine_type, I have to filter out the wine table and post filtered results. My approach so far doesn't work and I don't understand how to make it work using join tables. Here's what I have so far:

```
  <?php
if (count($_GET) > 0){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM winery where winery_name='".$_GET['winery_name']."'";
echo "Finished 1";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 2";

$row = $result->fetch_object();
$wineryid = $row -> winery_id;
echo "Winery id is ".$wineryid;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM wine where wine.winery_id =".$wineryid;
$result1 = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 4";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM wine_type where wine_type='".$_GET['wine_type']."'";
echo "Finished 5";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 6";

$row = $result->fetch_object();
$winetypeid = $row -> wine_type_id;
echo "Wine type id is ".$winetypeid;
//code stops working here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$result1." WHERE wine_type =".$winetypeid;
echo "Finished 8";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "Finished 9";

while($row = $result1->fetch_object()){

    echo $row->wine_name;
}

}
?>
```

Here's the ER diagram:
[image: ER Diagram]

Again, I am trying to go from winery_name(string) to winery_id(int) in `winery` and wine_type(string) to wine_type_id(int) in `wine_type`. Then using the int values to filter out wines from `wine` table. Also wine_type is an int value in in `wine` but string in `wine_type`.

If there is a way to make this statement work please let me know:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$result1." WHERE wine_type =".$winetypeid;
```

wine:
[image: wine]

winery
[image: winery]

wine_type
[image: wine_type]

Comment: *Sidenote curiousity:* Is this different than your other earlier posted question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36968358/ or is this one different? They look similar. (The graphic gave it away). ;-)

Comment: yes, it is different. That one was about syntax error but this one is about how to use return object as a table in sql.

Comment: Check for errors at the `code stops working here` point.. Also you are open to SQL injections with this code. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: How can I report errors in OO way using mysqli? my Mysqli object is called $db.

Comment: `wine_type='".$_GET['wine_type']."'` being a potential string and `WHERE wine_type =".$winetypeid;` being another potential string but using an "id" (int). Something doesn't add up here. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  and apply that to all your queries  and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Comment: Here `WHERE wine_type ='$winetypeid'";` that is for a (potential) string here, seems to be anyway.

Comment: i posted pictures of data in phpmyadmin u can see that wine_type is string in wine_type but int in wine.

Comment: any which way, you need to apply error checking in all your queries with `mysqli_error($db)`

Comment: i did this $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$result1." WHERE wine_type =".$winetypeid;
if (!$db->query($sql)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
}

Comment: but no error was reported when i ran it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on the web server. Once the Query results have been transferred from the database to the client Server, the database releases all references to the Query results.

This can be done with a nested select Statement:

```
SELECT a, b FROM (
    SELECT a, b FROM c JOIN d ON a =e
)
```